# Why isn't Nokogiri's xpath working as expected?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am parsing a Soap response with Nokogiri but for some reason the `xpath` or `css` methods can not find any tags beyond the `<soap:Body>` tag.

The XML I am trying to parse is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <AuthenticationResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <AuthenticationResult>
                <SessionID>clinTQYART6qxeQ%k^Am&amp;Sd5Co3</SessionID>
                <RequestStatus>1</RequestStatus>
                <RequestMessage>Success</RequestMessage>
            </AuthenticationResult>
        </AuthenticationResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If I inspect the parsed XML with a debugger I see

```
=> #(Document:0x3fce3c4dd95c {
  name = "document",
  children = [
    #(Element:0x3fce385b04dc {
      name = "Envelope",
      namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385b04b4 { prefix = "soap", href = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" }),
      children = [
        #(Element:0x3fce385e509c {
          name = "Body",
          namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385b04b4 { prefix = "soap", href = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" }),
          children = [
            #(Element:0x3fce385e4c64 {
              name = "AuthenticationResponse",
              namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385e4c14 { href = "http://tempuri.org/" }),
              children = [
                #(Element:0x3fce385e48a4 {
                  name = "AuthenticationResult",
                  namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385e4c14 { href = "http://tempuri.org/" }),
                  children = [
                    #(Element:0x3fce385e44f8 { name = "SessionID", namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385e4c14 { href = "http://tempuri.org/" }), children = [ #(Text "clinTQYART6qxeQ%k^Am&Sd5Co3")] }),
                    #(Element:0x3fce39dcff7c { name = "RequestStatus", namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385e4c14 { href = "http://tempuri.org/" }), children = [ #(Text "1")] }),
                    #(Element:0x3fce39dcfa2c { name = "RequestMessage", namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385e4c14 { href = "http://tempuri.org/" }), children = [ #(Text "Success")] })]
                  })]
              })]
          })]
      })]
  })
```

which is fine.

But `xml.xpath("//SessionID")` gives `[]`

However `xml.xpath("//soap:Body")[0]`  gives

```
=> #(Element:0x3fce385e509c {
  name = "Body",
  namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385b04b4 { prefix = "soap", href = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" }),
  children = [
    #(Element:0x3fce385e4c64 {
      name = "AuthenticationResponse",
      namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385e4c14 { href = "http://tempuri.org/" }),
      children = [
        #(Element:0x3fce385e48a4 {
          name = "AuthenticationResult",
          namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385e4c14 { href = "http://tempuri.org/" }),
          children = [
            #(Element:0x3fce385e44f8 { name = "SessionID", namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385e4c14 { href = "http://tempuri.org/" }), children = [ #(Text "clinTQYART6qxeQ%k^Am&Sd5Co3")] }),
            #(Element:0x3fce39dcff7c { name = "RequestStatus", namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385e4c14 { href = "http://tempuri.org/" }), children = [ #(Text "1")] }),
            #(Element:0x3fce39dcfa2c { name = "RequestMessage", namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385e4c14 { href = "http://tempuri.org/" }), children = [ #(Text "Success")] })]
          })]
      })]
  })
```

and `xml.xpath("//soap:Body")[0].children[0].children[0].children[0]` gives

```
=> #(Element:0x3fce385e44f8 { name = "SessionID", namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce385e4c14 { href = "http://tempuri.org/" }), children = [ #(Text "clinTQYART6qxeQ%k^Am&Sd5Co3")] })
```

and consequently `xml.xpath("//soap:Body")[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].content` gives me the correct id string.

So why doesn't `xml.xpath("//SessionID")` work?

Comment: You can use it like that but you would need to do `xml.remove_namespaces!` first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `SessionID` is in the namespace `http://tempuri.org/`.

Try something like (untested):

```
xml.xpath("//x:SessionID", {"x" => "http://tempuri.org/"})
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel — I've tried all sorts of combinations now and none of them work. I'll keep at it.

Comment: You could also try `//*[local-name()='SessionID']`

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if you're wanting to parse SOAP, you'd be better off using the `savon` gem rather than `nokogiri`. It's specifically designed to handle all the intricacies of SOAP.

Comment: yep I know. I was just trying to parse this manually for a unit test and it's bugging me that it's not working